# Android build system. Where is my wa.. native library?

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface, android-build

I trying to include a shared library through android build system. It named "**libmd5b**". I already check this library in NDK and it working well. But when I've built android I didn't found my library not in /system/lib and nor in else place. There is my actions step by step:

**1)** Put sources into ($AndroidSourceFolder)/external/libmd5b/jni

**Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -fPIC
LOCAL_LDLIBS     := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib
LOCAL_MODULE    := md5b
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := md5b.cpp md5.cpp # source files
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
# C++ inclusions:
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += libstlport_static
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += external/stlport/stlport bionic/ bionic/libstdc++/include
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**Application.mk**

```
APP_STL:=stlport_static
APP_MODULES := md5b
```

**md5b.cpp**

```
#include <jni.h> 
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <android/log.h>
#include "md5.h"
using namespace std;

extern "C" {
//Original name changed because we building library system wide visible.
     JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Md5B 
     (JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jstring fpath);
 };

 JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Md5B 
 (JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jstring fpath)
 {
     string strpath = env->GetStringUTFChars(fpath, NULL);
     ifstream inFile;
     inFile.open(strpath.c_str());
     string line;
     string strFile;
     while (!inFile.eof())
     {
         getline(inFile, line);
         strFile += line;
     }
     inFile.close();
     string md5R = md5(strFile);
     char* chmd5R = new char [md5R.length()];
     strcpy (chmd5R, md5R.c_str());
     return env->NewStringUTF(chmd5R);
 }
```

And there is other library files: [md5.cpp](http://goo.gl/7CBPS) and [md5.h](http://goo.gl/yhhb7). This files in pure C++ without any jni preparations. So I think it is no important.

**2)** Next step is changing ($AndroidSourceFolder)/build/target/product/**full.mk** to look like this:

```
PRODUCT_PACKAGES := \
    Camera \
    libmd5b

$(call inherit-product, $(SRC_TARGET_DIR)/product/full_base_telephony.mk)
$(call inherit-product, $(SRC_TARGET_DIR)/board/generic/device.mk)

# Overrides
PRODUCT_NAME := full
PRODUCT_DEVICE := generic
PRODUCT_BRAND := Android
PRODUCT_MODEL := Full Android on Emulator
```

**3)** After all this I launching it to compile:

```
$source build/envsetup.sh
$lunch full-eng
$make
```

**4)** Making libmd5b:

```
make md5b
<build information>
Install: out/target/product/generic/system/lib/md5b.so
```

That's it. After end of 'make' I can't found my library. It should be in /system/lib but it is not there. So where is my <strike>water</strike> library? And why I hasn't got any errors while compile it?

Comment: Yes. There appear in out/target/product/generic/system/lib/. But there still no in emulator image. And I thought it should be compiled in android compilation. What I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

There was error in Android.mk file in section named LOCAL_MODULE. Module should be named with lib* preffix:

```
lib<module name>
```